# If orange is hated by both men and women, why successful companies choose it?

Tags: color, color-scheme, branding

Reading [this site](https://www.websitebuilderexpert.com/designing-websites/how-to-choose-color-for-your-website/) on choosing colors, saw this infographic, claiming orange is most hateful to both men and women.

[image]

My question is why companies like Amazon chose orange as their primary color if it is disliked so much?

[image]

Comment: We can't really tell the real reason behind companies' color choices other than what is said in your last image. And there still might be other reasons.

Answer (score 4):

An obvious answer is that orange *isn't* disliked that much (or, at least, one shouldn't read too much into it).

Your question doesn't make it immediately clear that both images you show are from the same article ("*How to Choose a Good Color Scheme For Your Website*").

The image with the Amazon logo, claiming orange "*represents friendliness, enthusiasm & creativity*" is, apparently, created by the author(s) of the article ("*We’ve created a handy infographic to help you choose your perfect dominant color*") but they then go on to show the main infographic above, claiming orange is hated by both men and women. Below it they add the commentary:

> For instance, based on studies [...] Both genders also dislike orange and brown.  So if you are targeting both genders, the research says that it would be more advantageous to consider using blue or green as your dominant color

However, they do not address in anyway that this research is seemingly at odds with their earlier assertion that orange represents friendliness etc. (In fact, the above quote is their *only* use of the word "orange" in the article's main text).

**Possible reasons for the discrepancy?**

- The research asserting orange is hated was flawed.
- The research asserting orange represents friendliness was flawed.
- Both bits of research were more-or-less valid, but were, in effect, testing different things:

  - One might have focused on well-crafted logos/websites *using* the colours in question; the other might just have shown blocks of colour.
  - Any colour preference we have may be culture-dependent and the two surveys either didn't screen for this, or used cohorts from different cultures.
- We (the general populace) really don't have as much (consistent) colour preference as articles like this assert. They're measuring "wobbles" in essentially random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I would focus more on the issue of personal preferences on the psychology of color.

- Orange is a combination of yellow and red and is considered an
  energetic color.
- Orange calls to mind feelings of excitement,enthusiasm, and warmth.
- Orange is often used to draw attention, such as in traffic signs and advertising.
- Orange is energetic, which is   perhaps why many sports teams use
  orange in their uniforms, mascots, and branding.

The color selection is defined by the brand strategy and to create **differentiation** from competition.

The issue of proportion is also important, if orange is just an accent, it can be appreciated by both men and women.

Besides, more reliable research on preferences would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, choosing orange as the primary color for the logo (because this is what you gave as an example) is never a design/ UX decision, it is more a marketing decision.

Let's focus now on the UX part. Orange as brand color is not necessarily a bad UX because it can be used just in the logo or as an accent color in a website/ app.
In fact, if we consider aesthetic, psychological, and cultural associations, orange can be considered the right choice even as the primary color in some cases.

As a secondary color, its contrast to the other elements (mostly in the blue end of the spectrum), makes it firmly stand forward and this is a good practice.

As you can see, it is not so much to talk about orange in the UX context that is not primary-opinion based, but the elements that we can analyze don't give us any reason to not use orange. I used orange as an accent color in my corporate websites many times.

Answer (score -1):

There are countless examples of orange in branding, look at Mastercard. I really don't think their colour preferences correlate to the success of the business at hand. Amazon sells everything, Harley sells motorbikes to its loyal fans, the list goes on and on.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP is wondering *why* these companies are choosing orange, not who is using it, they already noted that companies like Harley Davidson and Amazon use orange in the question.

Comment: It isn't a question that can be easily answered otherwise it would have been. I think it would be better to highlight the indifference of using the colour to these companies, their success is not hinged on one study of the popularity of orange. This is to say to OP use whatever colour you feel represents your brand/project best. If your own research suggests orange is not good, don't use it just because Amazon do.